# Cell Phone bill calculator in C

Tags: c

I am attempting to write a program that will take a user's input for weekday, night, and weekend minutes and will spit out the average cost per minute, pretax bill, taxes, and total bill (according to flat rate/tax rate/additional weekday minute rate values given in the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define CENTS_PER_DOLLAR 100  
#define FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS 3999
#define TAX_RATE 0.05
#define ADDITIONAL_WEEKDAY_MIN_IN_CENTS 40

int main()
{
    int  weekdayMin, nightMin, weekendMin;
    float pretaxBill, taxes, totalBill, averageCost;

    printf("Please enter the number of weekday minutes, night minutes: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &weekdayMin, &nightMin);
    printf("Please enter the number of weekend minutes: ");
    scanf("%d", &weekendMin);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Weekday minutes: %d, night minutes: %d, weekend minutes: %d \n", weekdayMin, nightMin, weekendMin);
    averageCost = (weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin)/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
    printf("Average minute cost: $%.2f ", averageCost);
    if (weekdayMin <= 600)
    {
            pretaxBill = FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS;
            taxes = FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS*TAX_RATE;
            totalBill = pretaxBill + taxes;
            printf("Pretax bill: $%d \nTaxes: $%d \nTotal bill: $%d", pretaxBill, taxes, totalBill);
    }
    else
    {
            pretaxBill = (weekendMin - 600)*ADDITIONAL_WEEKDAY_MIN_IN_CENTS;
            taxes = pretaxBill*TAX_RATE;
            totalBill = pretaxBill + taxes;
            printf("Pretax bill: $", pretaxBill, "\nTaxes: $", taxes, "\nTotal bill: $\n", totalBill);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Whenever I run the program, it returns an average cost value of 0. I am aware that the rest of the code is not formatted correctly and when you run it there are many things wrong. I am just attempting to figure out how to get the value specified in the instructions from average cost per minute. However, any other advice or input about other parts of the program is appreciated. Im still very new to C so bear with me

THIS IS THE INTENDED OUTPUT

Please enter the number of weekday minutes, night minutes: 600 50 
Please enter the number of weekend minutes: 150

Weekday minutes: 600, night minutes: 50, weekend minutes: 150

Average minute cost: $0.05

Pretax bill: $ 39.99

Taxes: $ 2.10

Total bill: $ 42.09

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the calculation using integer variables, which can't represent fractions. You need to convert to float when doing the calculation:

```
averageCost = ((float)(weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin))/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
```

Assigning the result to a float doesn't cause it to do the computation as floats; it does the computation as ints, then converts the result (0) to float.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you calculate:

```
averageCost = (weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin)/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
```

you make integer division, and it evaluates to `0` if left operand is `less` than right operand of `/`.

You have to change `FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS` to float by adding following .0 in #definition,
or cast either left or right operand to float.

```
averageCost = (float)(weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin)/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
```

Remember to do cast **before** the division. If you do cast to float after division, result will be just 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with integer division. For instance, consider this line:

```
averageCost = (weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin)/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
```

`weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin` is an integer and so does `FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS`, so an integer division will take place. Now consider the values you entered:

```
weekdayMin = 600
weekendMin = 50
nightMin   = 150
FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS = 3999
```

The statement above evaluates as `800 / 3999`, which is `0`. Simple way to fix this is:

```
averageCost = 1.0 * (weekdayMin + weekendMin + nightMin)/(FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `weekdayMin`, `weekendMin` and `nightMin` are all `int` and your define `FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS` is also an `int` so you perform an integer division which will result in zero unless the sum of the minutes is larger than `FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS`. You need to cast on of the operands to float or define your `FLAT_RATE_IN_CENTS` as `3999.0f`.